# The Anonymous Visitor

Tags: java, allocation, anonymous, visitor-pattern

Sounds *creepy*, huh...

I'm developing a GUI-driven application which makes heavy use of the **Visitor Pattern**. I took this approach because it's important for me to handle a bunch of graphical elements in class-specific ways, though the classes themselves need to act as simple data objects. In this respect, they're totally agnostic to the multitude of scenarios they're subject to in my application logic.

The problem I have with this design choice is that as my application grows, I've found myself forced to make constant runtime allocations of [anonymous](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) Visitor implementations in order to describe my class-specific code in method bodies. Since many of these are dependent on the parameters provided at call time, I can't extract many of these to a reusable `static` implementation.

Here's an example, using a `Shaker` object, passed at runtime, to perform operations on types of `Button` only.

```
private abstract class Graphical implements Visitor.Dispatch {
    /* Position. */
    private int X;
    private int Y;
};

private final class Button extends Graphical {
    @Override public final void onVisit(final Visitor pVisitor) { pVisitor.onReceived(this); } };

private final class ScrollBar extends Graphical {
    @Override public final void onVisit(final Visitor pVisitor) { pVisitor.onReceived(this); }
};

public static interface Visitor {
    /* Adapter. */
    public static class Adapter implements Visitor {
        @Override public void onReceived(   Button    pButton) { }
        @Override public void onReceived(ScrollBar pScrollBar) { }
    };
    /* Dispatch Method. */
    public static interface Dispatch {
        public abstract void onVisit(final Visitor pVisitor);
    };
    /* Visitor Implementations. */
    public abstract void onReceived(final    Button    pButton);
    public abstract void onReceived(final ScrollBar pScrollBar);
};

/* Iterates through a List of Graphicals and Shakes a Button. */
public static void onShakeButtons(final List<Graphical> pGraphicals, final Shaker pShaker) {
    /* Allocate a Visitor. */
    final Visitor.Adapter lVisitor = new Visitor.Adapter() { @Override public void onReceived(final Button pButton) {
        /* Shake the Button! */
        pShaker.onShake(pButton);
    } };
    /* Iterate the Graphicals. */
    for(final Graphical lGraphical : pGraphicals) { lGraphical.onVisit(lVisitor); }
}
```

Can anyone suggest any suggestions on how to reduce the number of allocations I'm making? Or do I have a real misunderstanding about how the pattern should be applied?

Comment: Can you show a representative code example?

Comment: And what's the problem with creating objects? Java is an OO object. Creating objects is normal, expected and fast. Is there a concrete problem?

Comment: If you use Anonymous Visitors a lot you should consider using lambdas in Java 8 as these tend to be simpler and cleaner.

Comment: @PeterLawrey a visitor is rarely useful if it only has one abstract method. I don't really see how lambdas could help implementing a Visitor interface.

Comment: @JBNizet In the streams API, I consider the Predicate/Consumer/Function interfaces visitors to all the elements in the stream?

Comment: That's not an implementation of the visitor pattern though, which consists in having one seperate visit() method for every subclass of a base class (or interface): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Sources

Comment: @Fildor Added an example as requested.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree with you, but it's something I'd like to avoid if possible. I'm running some computationally intense algorithms, and due to the nature of the pattern I feel like I'm forced to make these seemingly superfluous allocations.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's a nice idea about Lambdas, the problem with multiple methods is often alleviated since I make use of an adapter of the Visitor pretty frequently. Unfortunately, I'm still using Java 7 like some caveman.

Comment: @AlexT. if you have a non-capturing lambda (one which doesn't use any variables by context) the JVM will implicitly cache them. Also Java 8's escape analysis is improved so objects which don't escape a method can be placed on the stack, avoiding a heap allocation.

Comment: @AlexT. I don't see 'parameters provided at call time' in your code example. Now you can just create an instance of ShakeVisitor and reuse it. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option.
You can create containers for your non-static object inside your visitor and update these containers with new non-static objects and reuse the visitor.

```
public class ConcreteVisitor extends Visitor {

        private final AtomicReference<MyClass> mValue_1 = new AtomicReference<MyClass>();

        private final AtomicReference<SomeClass> mValue_2 = new AtomicReference<SomeClass>();

        public void updateVisitor(MyClass newMyClass, SomeClass newSomeClass) {
            mValue_1.set(newMyClass)
            mValue_2.set(newSomeClass)
        }

        @Override
        public void visitElement_1(Element_1 element) {
            // use your updated values here
        }

        @Override
        public void visitElement_2(Element_2 element) {
            // use your updated values here
        }
    }
```

When you need to reuse the visitor, you just update the values and then run it again:

```
    // You create it only once:
    Visitor concreteVisitor = new ConcreteVisitor();

    // and reuse it all the time
    concreteVisitor.updateVisitor(newMyClass, newSomeClass);
    concreteVisitor.visitElement(element);
```

I use AtomicReference as a container, but can use your custom container class.

Comment: This is a nice idea, though I think it may be slightly inflexible (I'd have to allocate a number of specific implementations for each operation, of which there are many types.)  Also I have concerns about any long-lived references that would persist in rarely-used calls.